# Certain lib-files removed from linker command?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2012

I am trying to use parts of the OpenCV suite in an extension to a large project ([BCI2000](http://www.schalklab.org/research/bci2000)). While I have successfully compiled and executed [an OpenCV test program](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to), when linking OpenCV functions in the main program, linking fails with LNK2019: unresolved external symbol.
In the topmost property page, in the projects Property Manager, the following Command Line is shown:

> /OUT:"D:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\bci2k\build\CMakeFiles\custom\OpenCVTestSPModule\Release\OpenCVTestSPModule.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\bci2k\build\CMakeFiles\custom\OpenCVTestSPModule\Release\OpenCVTestSPModule.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "opencv_calib3d2410.lib" "opencv_contrib2410.lib" "opencv_core2410.lib" "opencv_features2d2410.lib" "opencv_flann2410.lib" "opencv_gpu2410.lib" "opencv_highgui2410.lib" "opencv_imgproc2410.lib" "opencv_legacy2410.lib" "opencv_ml2410.lib" "opencv_nonfree2410.lib" "opencv_objdetect2410.lib" "opencv_ocl2410.lib" "opencv_photo2410.lib" "opencv_stitching2410.lib" "opencv_superres2410.lib" "opencv_ts2410.lib" "opencv_video2410.lib" "opencv_videostab2410.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /PGD:"D:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\bci2k\build\CMakeFiles\custom\OpenCVTestSPModule\Release\OpenCVTestSPModule.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"OpenCVTestSPModule.dir\Release\OpenCVTestSPModule.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /LIBPATH:"D:\lib\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib" /TLBID:1

Meanwhile, in the Build Output box, the linking command executed confirms that the additional OpenCV LIBPATH:s have been included, but all the OpenCV .lib-files are missing, naturally resulting in this error.

> "/OUT:D:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\bci2k\build\CMakeFiles\custom\OpenCVTestSPModule\Release\OpenCVTestSPModule.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:D:\lib\opencv\build\x86\vc11\lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib ws2_32.lib ....\frameworks\LibTiny\Release\LibTiny.lib ....\frameworks\CoreLib\Release\BCI2000FrameworkCore.lib ws2_32.lib ....\frameworks\SigProcModuleLib\Release\BCI2000FrameworkSigProcModule.lib ....\frameworks\CoreLib\Release\BCI2000FrameworkCore.lib ....\frameworks\LibTiny\Release\LibTiny.lib ws2_32.lib winmm.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcprt /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd /MANIFEST "/MANIFESTUAC:level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed "/PDB:D:/Users/Admin/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/bci2k/build/CMakeFiles/custom/OpenCVTestSPModule/Release/OpenCVTestSPModule.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT "/IMPLIB:D:/Users/Admin/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/bci2k/build/CMakeFiles/custom/OpenCVTestSPModule/Release/OpenCVTestSPModule.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /machine:X86 /include:_SigProcRegistry OpenCVTestSPModule.dir\Release\PipeDefinition.obj

The "Additional Include Directories" and "Additional Dependencies" are in the same Property Sheet, so evidently the property sheet is read at compile time. Does anyone have an idea what may cause this issue? Target is Win32(Release), IDE is VS2012.

Might be related: In the Property Manager, a property sheet called "Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user" exists. If one tries to move this upwards (later in evaluation), an error ("Could not find the import for (path to this prop-file) in an import group with label "PropertySheets" and (condition) in the file (path to project)") is shown.

Priority of property sheets can be rearranged without problems in the test program.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your project's Linker + Input + Additional dependencies setting is missing `%(AdditionalDependencies)`  So you didn't get the dependencies from the property sheet.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Initially, it seemed incorrect, as this was appended on all property sheets I was looking at, but, given a week away from the problem, I went to project->properties instead of the property manager. Where I finally found the field with the missing %(AdditionalDependencies).

If you post your comment as an answer I can mark it right away.